# Темный titlebar в intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, windows-10

Сижу, значит, пишу код в `Intellij` с темой `Darcula`, и понимаю - так жить больше нельзя, ибо белый заголовок окна очень навязчиво светит в глаза. Погуглив по этому поводу, для винды ничего не нашел.

Есть ли способ сменить цвет заголовка? Может если не через настройки `ide`, то используя какие-то установки в системе для конкретного приложения?

Answer (score 1):

Правой кнопкой мыши по рабочему столу, выбираешь 'персонализация" и там в "цвета" и меняй!